# How do I get objects to follow another mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh

I have a "book" mesh that is rigged and sample objects on the surface.  When the book opens, I want the spheres to follow and keep their current location.  The only way this works is if I make the spheres part of the same mesh, which I do not want to do. I also don't want the spheres to be part of the same amature as the book.  They will have their own amatures. I want them to remain in their static location when the book opens.  Is there a way to keep the spheres at the static locations on image 2?

Is there a trick using empties?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can parent your balls to a vertex or to some vertices of your plane: Select a ball, shift select the plane, go in *Edit* mode, select a vertex or some vertices and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*.

Comment: Thanks, I have the option but it's giving me a new error now. "Select at least 1 or 3 vertices to parent".  I tried selecting only 1.. Now 3, I get the same error.

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/